# database to use in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3

As I am novice to swift 3.0,
I am too much confused , how to use sqlite3 in swift 3.0

- while working with objective-C I have used sqlite3 without any 3rd party library.
- Same I want to do with swift 3.0
- As I have searched over net, I saw various libraries are being used
  i.e. FMDB , GRDB , Sqlite.Swift ,etc.
- is there any way to use sqlite without third party library?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

Comment: Why did you revert the title change? You are not asking which database to use since you already know you wish to use SQLite. Your entire question is about using SQLite without a 3rd party library.